# First to enumerate integer partitions?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

G.E. Andrews writes, "Leibniz was apparently the first person to ask about partitions. In a 1674 letter he asked J. Bernoulli about the number of “divulsions” of integers. In modern terminology, he was asking the first question about the number of partitions of integers. He observed that there are three partitions of 3 (3, 2 + 1, and 1 + 1 + 1) as well as five of 4 (4, 3 + 1, 2 + 2, 2 + 1 + 1 and 1 + 1 + 1 + 1)."

I find this assertion of priority incredibly difficult to believe as well as the following:

Peter Luschny, an editor for the OEIS commenting on simply an allusion to a listing of integer partitions, certainly not an attribution as to the first publication with that order, "I strongly appeal against the terms A&S-order or A-St-order. Whoever (...?) introduced these terms into the OEIS made a disservice. It is well known that this widely used order was introduced by C. F. Hindenburg in his 1779 dissertation and the proper way to reference it is either 'Hindenburg order' or a mathematical description in general terms. Neither Abramowitz nor Stegun have ever written a single line about monomial orders, not even in their Handbook. A detailed analysis of the Hindenburg way to enumerate the partitions can be found Knuth's chapter 7 in TAOCP 4. The term A&S does not appear a single time in this work. Let us base our terminology on serious literature rather than introduce private jargon into OEIS."

I would assume that the ancient Babylonians and Chinese had addresssed the topic long before either of these two mathematicians (in diverse, reasonable, and exhaustive orderings), and that this OCD necessitating attributing priority to particular, long-deceased individuals is both gratuitous and naive.

Accordingly, to support a definitive rebuttal of these somewhat trivial assertions and much more importantly to discourage such scholasticism in general, can anyone provide references on earlier investigations of the integer partitions?

(Some indication of interests of the ancients in integer partitions: The oldest known magic square dates to 2200 BCE (Cf: [A brief survey of combinatorics)](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/mis_10_encyclopedia.pdf).

Comment: Earlier than what ? After Leibniz, we have **Ch.XVI DE PARTITIONE NUMERORUM** of Leonhard Euler, [Introductio in analysin infinitorum](https://books.google.it/books?id=_zpRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA253) (1748).

Comment: See Brian Hopkins a and Robin Wilson, [Euler’s Science of Combinations](http://www.gss.ucsb.edu/sites/secure.lsit.ucsb.edu.germ.d7/files/sitefiles/news/conferences/euler/Hopkins2.pdf) for modern comment.

Comment: I am not aware of combinatorial problems in ancient Babylonian, Egyptian or Chinese sources (I Ching and Lo Shu can be related to it today, but there is no sign of that in contemporary sources), and of only one in the entire Greek corpus. Even permutations and combinations first appear in India only in 6th century AD, and it is a step up in abstraction from counting collections of objects to counting *ways* to partition. Probability does not appear before 17th century despite prolific gambling in antiquity. So I am inclined to credit Andrews's claim.

Comment: @Conifold, read about the 4,000 year old magic squares and google the historical significance of the number $108 = 1^1 2^2 3^3$ which you could consider as a type of partitioning. It's an ancient number found thoughout Asia (India, China, S.E. Asia, Japan) in the major indigenous religions and, consequently, in religious architecture and partitionings of the seasons and aspects of human nature. The Japanese still ring the bells of shrines 108 times around midnight on New Year's Eve.

Comment: (cont.)  I'm inclined not to be Eurocentric about the origins of such simple concepts. The concepts of permutation and combinations are natural and most certainly were employed on the battlefield by commanders in combining and permuting arrays of troops and in the kitchen by innovative chefs. As far as the terminology, a rose is a rose ... . I think there is a conflation here between the construction of a systematic theory and the origins of the basic underlying concept, as in your example of probability.

Comment: (cont) From Wikipedia: "Combinatorics is a branch of mathematics concerning the study of finite or countable discrete structures. Aspects of combinatorics include counting the structures of a given kind and size (enumerative combinatorics) ... ." So, look at the wheat-and-chessboard problem and its origins, a problem in combinatorics.

Comment: I am familiar with all of that. We can take puzzles, ritualistic texts or calendars, and consider them in the light of modern combinatorics. But that is different from *them* doing it by presenting combinatorial recipes, calculations or concepts, let alone as abstract as partitions. We have texts showing what mathematical problems ancient cultures saw as problems they were solving, combinatorial ones are not there. Even in hindsight the "partitionings" you mention fall far more naturally under permutations and combinations than partitions, and those do appear earlier.

Comment: Its a little dubious basing inclinations on ignorance.

Comment: A magic square, a 2-dimensionally interrelated partioning of an integer, is a much more "abstract" and difficult construct than a simple linear partition of the integers. If you don't think the Chinese were aware that they were solving a mathematical problem (by whatever name) and didn't first write out lists of linear partitions of integers (Leibniz's divulsions) in order to construct the squares, then we have no common ground for further discussion.

Comment: Nārāyaṇa Paṇḍita in his Gaṇita-kaumudī (c. 1356) enumerates ordered q-partitions of an integer, i.e. the number of ways of writing an integer n as an ordered sum of parts all ≤ q. (He was generalizing from an earlier (centuries-old) enumeration of the number of ways of writing n as a sum of 1s and 2s, which gives the Fibonacci numbers.) However I'm not aware of him enumerating unordered partitions.

Comment: Srinivasa Ramanujan contributed  also discovering that congruences in the number of partitions exist for some groups of integers... 

There is also a movie about his life where some of this area is dramatized in a "more-or-less" romantic way though...

"https://youtu.be/NP0lUqNAw3k"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, interesting. Are there some refs on the Web?

Comment: On ancient studies in combinatorics, note the work of Pingala citca 500-300 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingala and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_combinatorics.

Comment: @TomCopeland See ["Nārāyaṇa Paṇḍita's enumeration of combinations and associated representation of numbers as sums of binomial coefficients" by Sridharan, Sridharan and Srinivas, _Indian Journal of History of Science,_ 47.4 (2012) 607-631](http://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJHS/Vol47_4_5_RSridhan.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Leibniz published in a book regarding this problem prior any of those letters.

Leibnuetzio, Gottfredo, 1666, *Dissertatio De Arte Combinatoria*, Lipsiae: Ficki, Seubold, p. 59. (Problem 3)

The fact that this is listed as a problem he is trying to solve suggests the problem is much older. Which it probably is ... because of gambling. Likely this is one of the earlier publications however.

Euler published (as M.A. pointed out) his book somewhat later but gave a general formula and the modern statement (and name) of the problem.

Eulero, Leonhardo, 1748, *Introductio In Analysin Infinitorum*, I, Lausannae: Bousquet, p. 255.